# Custom urls with Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I am creating a blog made with Umbraco 6 and I'd like to customize the urls.

When I create a blog post, the post is organized with the year/month/day structure and the url for post is blog.com/2013/2/19/title.aspx.

I'd like to keep the folder organization, but I'd like to change the url to blog.com/title.aspx

Is that possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to use the [umbracoUrlAlias](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracourlalias) property. On publish you could set the umbracoUrlAlias to the title. You may want to include some logic that ensures that the url is unique. You will also have to revise your navigation macros to use umbracoUrlAlias if there is one present instead of the NiceUrl.

Comment: updated link: https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Routing/routing-properties